# R commands in tidyverse

Tags: r, csv

Below you find the R code for my work. I am new with R and I need some help with the package tidyverse and some quite simpel tasks.

1. I would like to create a new table with my last comande and call it. Year_mean
2. I would like to extract my data to excel.

And I cant understand why the specific variabel "Laender Welt --- Laender" doesnt give me any results?
Can I attach the csv files? Maybe that helps?

Thank you in advance
Oliver

````
# packages ----------------------------------------------------------------

(tidyverse) ```

rm(list=ls())```

load data ---------------------------------------------------------------

setwd("C:\Users\olive\Desktop\BA Studien\R Daten BA\Daten")
im <- read.csv(file = "import.csv")
ex <- read.csv(file = "export.csv")


# combine -----------------------------------------------------------------

im_ex <- expand_grid(Year = sort(unique(c(im$Year, ex$Year))),
Country = sort(unique(c(im$PartnerName, ex$ReporterName))))

ex <- ex %>%
mutate(Country = ReporterName,
ex = `TradeValue.in.1000.USD`) %>%
select(Year, Country, ex)

im <- im %>%
mutate(Country = PartnerName,
im = `TradeValue.in.1000.USD`) %>%
select(Year, Country, im)



im_ex <- im_ex %>%
left_join(ex) %>%
left_join(im) %>%
mutate(gap = log(1 + im) - log(1 + ex))


im_ex[,3:4][is.na(im_ex[,3:4])] <- 0

im_ex <- im_ex %>%
left_join(ex) %>%
left_join(im) %>%
mutate(gap = log(1 + im) - log(1 + ex))


# plot --------------------------------------------------------------------

im_ex %>%
filter(Country == "Germany") %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = gap)) +
geom_line()

im_ex %>%
filter(Country == "Germany") %>%
as_tibble()

im_ex %>%
filter(Country == "United Arab Emirates") %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = gap)) +
geom_line()

im_ex %>%
filter(Country == "United Arab Emirates") %>%
as_tibble()

im_ex %>%
filter(Country == "Afghanistan") %>%
as_tibble()


im_ex %>%
filter(Country == "Laender Welt --- Laender") %>%
as_tibble()

im_ex %>%
filter(Country == "United States") %>%
as_tibble()

im_ex %>%
filter(Country == "United States") %>%
as_tibble()

# Summary Stat ------------------------------------------------------------

## Average Gap per country

im_ex %>%
group_by(Country) %>%
summarise(nr_of_obs = sum(!is.na(gap)),
gap = mean(gap, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
arrange(gap) %>%
filter(!is.na(gap)) %>%
View()

im_ex %>%
group_by(Year) %>%
summarise(nr_of_obs = sum(!is.na(gap)),
gap = mean(gap, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
arrange(gap) %>%
filter(!is.na(gap)) %>%
view()
````

Comment: I guess you want to write the summarised output to excel.

Comment: There isn't any country called `Laender Welt --- Laender`

Comment: @akrun exactly. and maybe some other table. It would be helpfull to know the general way of doing that.

Comment: @HongOoi I know that. These is a summary of all the countries I looked at. Is there a way to post the excel list. Maybe then you can see what im doing wrong?

Comment: You are filtering data multiple times without assigning to new object.  Perhaps you can do it once with `im_ex %>% filter(Country %in% c("United States",  ...))`  Assign to a new obejct i.e. `%>% filter(!is.na(gap))-> sum_im_ex` and then use `write.xlsx(sum_im_ex, 'yourfile.xlsx')`

Comment: Then i would get a singel tabel for the selected countries right?

Comment: @akrun I get an error that it cant find the wirte.xlsx as a command. Do I need to instal a package?

Comment: there are lots of packages for writing in excel.  Try `openxlsx` or `write_xlsx` from `writexl`

Comment: @akrun thank you so much for your effort. I have a last question. But without you having the data I dont think you can answer it. Am I right that I cant attach any csv data here?

Comment: As i mentione din the code above.  load th package i.e. `library(openxlsx);` then write the object `write.xlsx(sum_im_ex, 'yourfile.xlsx')`